# why images are not displayed with odbc connection?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, powerbuilder

If i make odbc connection for PowerBuilder datawindow then images are not show. But, Native connections shows all images row by row in my datawindow.

How to show images with ODBC connection in PowerBuilder?

I use oledb column in my datawindow.

Comment: Versions would be helpful here.

Comment: PowerBuilder version 12.5,
SQL Server 2008 R2,
ODBC 11 and 10 were checked

Answer (score 0):

Select to collect the image blob from the database and then convert the blob to file and assign it to an image object. Example:

```
Blob bScreen

SELECTBLOB SCREEN
        INTO :bScreen
        FROM <Table>
      WHERE ID = :lID
      USING SQLCA;

uoFunc.uof_BlobToFile( bScreen, sRuta )

p_3.PictureName = sRuta   //picture object
```

Comment: Hola amigo: Can you do the same thing in a datawindow without using picture object? I want to see all images row by row because all rows in database have unique images with them. Thanks and please do not forget that the only option is ODBC and i want to use OLEDB Column.

Comment: Let us make it simple: I can code the retrieve row event but i dont know how to set OLE DB Column with value of blob variable in retrieverow event. Could you please give a sample code for that?   :)